# SharpZipLib - adding a ZipEntry to a ZipFile throws a ZipException

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I'm trying to create ZIP with file from in-memory string and save it. Here is my code so far:

```
var zip = ZipFile.Create(Path.Combine(outputPath, fileName));
zip.BeginUpdate();

var fileStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myStringVariable));
var outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();
var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream);
var zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file.html");

zipEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
zipStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
StreamUtils.Copy(fileStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
zipStream.CloseEntry();
zip.Add(zipEntry);

zip.CommitUpdate();
zip.Close();
```

However it breaks on zip.Add(zipEntry); and throws exception:

> **ZipException** - Entry cannot have any data

Somehow I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ZipFile.Add` method override you're using is for adding directories, volume labels, etc. to a zip file: it [explicitly throws a `ZipException`](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/3285f157292b1ced64459d89207d335f9a6879ee/src/Zip/ZipFile.cs#L1738) if you pass a `ZipEntry` containing data.

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Updating) if you want to add in-memory data to a `ZipFile`, you need to use the `Add(IStaticDataSource dataSource, string entryName)` override. You'll also need to create an implementation of `IStaticDataSource` (the one below is taken from the documentation page).

So your code would be something like:

```
void Main()
{
    string outputPath = @"C:\Scratch\test.zip";
    string myStringVariable = "<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>Hello World</body></html>";

    var zip = ZipFile.Create(outputPath);
    zip.BeginUpdate();

    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myStringVariable));

    var dataSource = new CustomStaticDataSource();
    dataSource.SetStream(fileStream);

    zip.Add(dataSource, "file.html");

    zip.CommitUpdate();
    zip.Close();
}

public class CustomStaticDataSource : IStaticDataSource {
    private Stream _stream;
    // Implement method from IStaticDataSource
    public Stream GetSource() {
        return _stream;
    }

    // Call this to provide the memorystream
    public void SetStream(Stream inputStream) {
        _stream = inputStream;
        _stream.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it works. However I have to admit it's not intuitive solution.