# How write memorystream into ZipFile

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I have a zip file. I want open it with SharpZipLib and add a new ZipEntry to it that it is created in memory.
I am new to SharpZipLib. I googled very much but couldn't find similar problem.

My Sample Code is:

```
public Stream GetNewZipFileStream(string zipFilePath)
{
   byte[] zipFileBytes = null;
   zipFileBytes = ReadFileBytes(zipFilePath);
   var zipFileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(zipFileBytes);

   ZipOutputStream zipOutStream = new ZipOutputStream(zipFileMemoryStream);

   var newEntry = new ZipEntry("NewFile.txt");
   zipOutStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

   var newFileMemoryStream = MakeOnTheFlyStream();
   StreamUtils.Copy(newFileMemoryStream , zipOutStream, new byte[4096]);

   zipOutStream.CloseEntry();
   newFileMemoryStream.Close();
   zipOutStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
   zipOutStream.Close();
   newFileMemoryStream.Position = 0;
   return newFileMemoryStream;
}
```

`ReadFileBytes` and `MakeOnTheFlyStream` are my methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356003/c-sharp-sharpziplib-adding-file-to-existing-archive

Comment: where is your try? add some code to know where and what problem you are getting?

Comment: @user2932057 No, It's different. I need to write an stream into a ZipEntry and add it to an existing zip file.

Comment: That's what that other question is doing, too.

Comment: @Amy All of that solutions add new file from hard with a path. But I generate my file stream with `MakeOnTheFlyStrem` and I don't want to save it on hard because of security reasons. So I have a FileStream and I want to add it to ZipFile.

Comment: @MohammadAliTaqvazadeh They open that file off the hard drive... *as a stream*.  You already have a stream.  So *skip* the part where they load the file.

Comment: @Amy I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356306/7672704) but when I opened my new zip file I got this error: _The archive is either in unknown format or damaged_

Comment: Finally I found appropriate solution: [SharpZipLib - adding a ZipEntry to a ZipFile throws a ZipException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28631536/7672704)